# What hosted-commenting tools produce clean markup?

Tags: comments

You may be familiar with IntenseDebate, Disqus, and their ilk. These tools produce wretched markup that pollutes my pages significantly and is difficult to style correctly.

I have a site which is statically generated. Are there hosted commenting options that are simple, clean, unobstrusive, and easy to style?

Comment: dz from disqus here: we certainly don't mean to produce wretched markup :) if you'd like, ping me (dz@disqus.com) with any markup queries, and i'll try to fix it.  certain markup might be constructed in a less than ideal manner for maximum compatibility, fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I settled on was using hosted-commenting JSON APIs plus JS templating. You give up the social-media button widgets and you have to roll some of your own comment form, but that's ultimately a small price to pay in my book.